# How to disable Touch support in GXT 4?

Tags: extjs, gwt, gxt

I'm making build, where I've added `"edge"` in `"gxt.user.agent"` and it enables lots of unneccessary gesture stuff. How can I disable it? `gxt.device` is set to `"desktop"`

Error on start :

`java.lang.IllegalStateException: Event system already initialized at Unknown.java_lang_Throwable_Throwable__Ljava_lang_String_2V(bootstrap-0.js@8:1740) at Unknown.java_lang_Exception_Exception__Ljava_lang_String_2V(bootstrap-0.js@55:5413) at Unknown.java_lang_RuntimeException_RuntimeException__Ljava_lang_String_2V(bootstrap-0.js@55:5423) at Unknown.new java_lang_IllegalStateException_IllegalStateException__Ljava_lang_String_2V(bootstrap-0.js@69:20816) at Unknown.com_google_gwt_user_client_impl_DOMImplStandard_ensureInit__V(bootstrap-0.js@87:11298) at Unknown.com_sencha_gxt_core_client_gestures_impl_PointerEventsSupportImpl_$clinit__V(bootstrap-0.js@5:15166) at Unknown.com_sencha_gxt_core_client_gestures_PointerEventsSupport_$clinit__V(bootstrap-0.js@3:14668) at Unknown.com_sencha_gxt_cell_core_client_AbstractEventCell_$addCellGestureAdapter__Lcom_sencha_gxt_cell_core_client_AbstractEventCell_2Lcom_sencha_gxt_core_client_gestures_CellGestureAdapter_2V(bootstrap-0.js@5:4934) at`

Comment: Why do you need it disabled? If the user isn't touching their screen, it shouldn't be responding to touches, right?

Comment: @ColinAlworth because it's not needed. Idk why secnha team decided implement 'GXT.isTouch()' check for tablet OR MS Edge. Also it throws a lot of exceptions like "Event system already initialized" on components gestures initialization

Comment: I was involved there when it was started, but the "pointer event" system is what MS Edge used at the time, which covers both touch and mouse, so being "too broad" in making sure it worked was ideal - and as I recall, Edge gave no hint as to whether or not a touch screen was enabled, so you had to just always be ready for it. I can't speak to the exceptions without more information about the error.

Comment: @ColinAlworth updated with stacktrace

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The addCellGestureAdapter (the top of the stack in the question - it isn't clear what is calling it since the stack is so short) is being called too late. The `DomImplStandard.ensureInit()` method is designed to be called very early, before any element has listeners attached, so that the correct handlers can be ready for any element that is attached.

GXT 4 sources are not publicly available, and support is pretty thin (Sencha made a [blog post](https://www.sencha.com/blog/sencha-on-stack-overflow/) discussing how StackOverflow should be used instead of their own forums, but they don't actually seem to check StackOverflow), but I think there is a method that you can call earlier in your page lifecycle to get this going. Try adding this line as one of the first lines in your onModuleLoad, to ensure that it is wired up before the very first element is attached:

```
PointerEventsSupport.impl.isSupported();
```

You don't even need to use the return value, but just checking it should be enough to ensure that everything is wired up early enough. This isn't mentioned in any of their [docs about getting started with touch](https://docs.sencha.com/gxt/4.x/guides/getting_started/Getting_Started_with_Touch.html), so I have to assume that this usually wires up correctly automatically, and that there is something unique about your application that prevents this.